# Absolute convergence in normed space

Tags: normed-spaces, absolute-convergence

1. There is example when convergent sequence does not implies absolute convergence.

[image]

2. In wikipedia there is written that for absolute convergence we need norm. So we talk about absolute convergence only in the norm space.

[image]

Question. How to link this and the example above where we see that convergence does not implies absolute convergence? My thoughts: if we talk about absolute convergence then it implies that we talk about normed space. In normed space convergence implies absolute convergence. What do I misunderstand?

EDIT:  An idea that in normed space convergence implies absolute convergence was taken from this paper. [image]

Comment: If you want to link the two you have to consider normed vector spaces otherwise you do not have addition to discuss convergence of infinite sums, that is what you are interested in. You say: "in normed space convergence implies absolute convergence.". Why do you say that? In normed vector spaces convergence to a point implies that the norm of the difference from that point goes to zero. For infinite sums, it means that the norm of the distance from the finite sum to the limit goes to zero. This is not a notion of absolute congervegence, where one would sum up the norms of the addends.

Comment: Maybe some mathematician can confirm if I said smth wrong...

Comment: I guess you can apply the above ideas not only to normed vector spaces but also to topological groups with the norm as you defined... indeed there also you have additions and can build finite sums so the first part my first comment was slightly wrong....

Comment: Why I said? I added a picture. This three different sourses confuse me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to define partial sums, we need to have some notion of addition. Then, once we have partial sums, we can define the limit of a series in terms of the convergence of the partial sums. If we define absolute convergence in terms of the absolute value of each term, that requires that the absolute value function be defined. Norms are a generalization of the absolute value.

That is, if we have a function $N$, we can ask whether $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^kN(a_n)$ exists. If $N$ is a norm, then convention is that $||x||$ represents $N(x)$, so the preceding expression becomes $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^k||a_n||$. When we're talking about a general space, just having a binary operator defined does not allow us to speak of the absolute value (for instance, what's the absolute value of a permutation?).

> In normed space convergence implies absolute convergence.

No, the example of $\frac {(-1)^n}n$ shows that in a normed space, convergence does *not* imply absolute convergence. That is, in spaces with a norm, "convergence implies absolute convergence" is false. In spaces without a norm, "convergence implies absolute convergence" is meaningless, because the entire concept of "absolute convergence" depends on a norm for its definition.

Comment: The last picture is from this source math.usm.edu/lee/mat771/hw3sol.pdf. Page 5, section 5. So there is mistake in this paper? If yes then I understand your anwer very well.

Comment: The article looks good quality at a first glance but that sentence looks not correct

Comment: @Thomas Thanks! Now I am happy