# Convervence in the normed space.

Tags: normed-spaces, uniform-convergence, complete-spaces, absolute-convergence

By definition a sequence convergence in normed space if

$||x_n-x||\le \varepsilon \;\forall n \gt N.$

And this limit must be the element of this space. Does it mean that space must be complate by default?

EDIT: Or can every sequence converges in noncomplate normed space?

Comment: A sequence $(x_n)$ in a normed space $X$ converges if there exists some $x \in X$, such that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $N$ such that $\|x_n - x\| < \varepsilon$ (or $\le \varepsilon$; it doesn't matter) for all $n > N$. Importantly, the $x$ is assumed by definition to be in the space. How would it make sense otherwise? What would it mean for, say, a sequence of real numbers to converge to a $2 \times 2$ matrix? We need $x \in X$ by default, otherwise nothing about the definition makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: maybe you are confusing the convergence of a sequence with the convergence of all sequences. In general, we say that if $(X,||\cdot ||)$ is a normed space, then a sequence $\{x_n \}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to a point $x\in X$ if for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, if $n\geq N$, then $||x_n-x||<\varepsilon$. On the other side, we say that a normed (or more general, metric) space $Y$ is complete if every Cauchy sequence in $Y$ converges to some element in $Y$. With this, is it clear the difference between the two things?

For your last question, the answer is no. If $X$ is a normed space and every sequence converges, in particular every Cauchy sequence converges. Thus, $X$ is complete by definition. (Note that here the word *converges* meaning *converges to some point of the space*).

Comment: Yes! It makes sence! Thanks! I dont know can I do this here but in any case. It would be very helpfull if you could say something in this topic https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4191974/absolute-convergence-in-normed-space in your free time. I am confused by one paper.